# How to check if an int array is a circularly sorted array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an integer array, say `{1, 3, 4, 7, -9, 0}`. This array is *circularly sorted*, while the array `{2, 4, 9 , 3}` is not circularly sorted.

An array is circularly sorted if its elements are sorted except for a rotation.

For example:

```
4 5 6 7 1 2 3
```

The elements here, `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`, are "in order", but they are rotated to the left by three. So if we rotate to the right by 3 we get `1 2 3 4 5 6 7` which is a sorted array.

Given an array, how can you check whether the array is a circularly sorted?

Comment: Maybe you would like to share with us whatever you have tried so far?

Comment: that means when you given an array, how can you check the array is the Circularly Sorted Array

Comment: We got that part, but I don't understand what ***is*** a circularly sorted array.  What is its definition.

Comment: For example:

4 5 6 7 1 2 3

The elements here, (1 2 3 4 5 6 7), are "in order," but they are rotated to the left by three.

Comment: @khuong291 The question is absolutely perfect. But let me ask you have you tried solving it.? or how do u approach the problem?

Comment: Of course yes, but I have to use a lot of loops here, can u give me some hint on faster way!!

Comment: @khuong291, Hint you require only one loop and tricky condition check. its not that complex. Once the post is reopened i can give you a code snippet.

Comment: I've voted to reopen. I very recently encountered this question as well and found a solution. There's a brute force way to do it, and there's an elegant way to do it...which do you want? :P

Comment: Count how many times `value[i] > value[(i+1)%length]`. If the answer is 0 or 1, it is circularly sorted.

Comment: @Tom: That example would return a count of 2 right? `7 > -9`, and `2 > 1`

Comment: @Tom, That's what the `(i+1)%length` is for. It checks the last number (2 in your example) is greater than the first number (1 in your example). Because `2>1` then this algorithm would have two "breaks" and fail. Have a look at the edited example in my answer, I added your test case.

Comment: @SamuelO'Malley Yes, you're right, the `%length` part ensures the check of the last element with the first one. Missed that :(. The problem was the missing parenthese in user3437460s answer, which I used to check the algorithm.

Comment: @Khuong This is very late but this algorithm is broken. You *do* need to check against the least element in the first ascending segment. There isn't an inductive way to solve this problem. For example, try calling `is_circular_sorted([1,2,3,4,2,3,4])`. This returns `true` when [1,2,3,4,2,3,4] is clearly not circularly sorted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can loop through the array and check that all values are increasing. And as soon as you hit the first value that is not increasing, check that it and all of the following values are increasing AND less than or equal to the first element in the array.

Edit:

I feel that people are discounting Daniel's solution because they don't understand it or think it is broken. This is sad because I think his solution is brilliant.

```
def is_circular_sorted(arr):
    count = 0
    length = len(arr)
    for i in range(length):
        if arr[i] > arr[(i+1) % len(arr)]:
            count += 1
    return count <= 1

In [4]: is_circular_sorted([1, 2, 3, 4])
Out[4]: True

In [5]: is_circular_sorted([1, 1, 1, 1])
Out[5]: True

In [6]: is_circular_sorted([1, 3, 4, 7, -9])
Out[6]: True

In [7]: is_circular_sorted([1, 3, 4, 2])
Out[7]: False
```

For a little bit of explanation. To check if a list is circular-sorted, my original answer said you needed to check there was one or less "break" from being completely sorted AND all of the numbers after the "break" were less than the first number in the array.

However as Daniel's answer shows, you don't need to check ALL numbers after the "break", only the last number (which also happens to be the biggest/maximum number after the break because they are sorted).

There should always be one break, unless the list is filled with the same numbers in which case there would be no breaks and count would be 0.

Comment: Less than *or equal to*, but yes.

Comment: @khuong291: no you should be able do this in a single loop through.

Comment: I would start by finding the smallest number and then checking if all succeeding numbers are greater, but this also works.

Answer (score 4):

In case some of the users wonder how the implementation looks like.

```
public boolean isCircularSorted(int[] array)
{
    int size = array.length;
    int count = 0;

    for(int x=0; x<size; x++)
        if(array[x] > array[(x+1)%size])
            count ++;
    return (count <= 1);
}
```

This was also mentioned by user Daniel.

Comment: @SamuelO'Malley I rejected your edit because what you suggested in the edit was my first draft. count need not necessary must be `==0 || ==1`. Since count can never falls below 0, it is alright to write `count <= 1` which only consist of 0 or 1. The curly braces for the for-loop is also unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry @user3437460, I noted that it was incorrect a while back and didn't realise that you had changed the `>=` to the `<=` in the mean time.

Comment: @SamuelO'Malley For Samuel and Tom: No problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

As @Daniel said, using `value[i] > value[(i+1)%length]`, if it `true` we count up 1, if the `count` at the end equals to `0` or `1`, the original `array` is circularly sorted array! I think it is a good way!!

Comment: You're right this is a good answer, but if you are going to take an answer from a comment I think you should try to put an example or explanation to show how it works. That way everyone will understand it.